# putting p tags on pulled content - Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site which pulls the text out of the posts and displays them using

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <p>
    <?php
        echo preg_replace('/(<img [^>]*>)/', '', get_the_content());
    ?>
  </p>
</div>
```

however this wraps everything in one p tag (despite having multiple paragraphs in the post) How can I put the < p > tags back on each paragraph in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `wpautop()` like this:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <p>
    <?php
        $content = preg_replace('/(<img [^>]*>)/', '', get_the_content());
        $content = wpautop($content); // Add paragraph-tags
        $content = str_replace('<p></p>', '', $content); // remove empty paragraphs
        echo $content;
    ?>
  </p>
</div>
```

`get_the_content()` doesn't add p-tags as default like `the_content()` does.

Read more about: `wpautop()` here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop

Comment: it seems to put an empty paragraph after each of mine?

Comment: I though you didn't get any p-tags except one? (isn't that the one in your HTML-markup?)

Comment: exactly, now I'm getting my content in p tags like i want, but now theres extra ones

Comment: Ah... yes.. Now I get it. (It's morning here... haven't really woken up). :) That's wordpress way of handling empty lines....  try sending `true` as a second parameter to the `wpautop()` function.

Comment: i'm a bit of a noob, how to add second parameter?

Comment: Updated again. :) If you still want a HTML-line break but just not a p-tag... you can change `str_replace('<p></p>', '', $content)` to `str_replace('<p></p>', '<br />', $content)`. Test both and see which suites you best.

Comment: still getting same results. Weird. I just have a few paragraphs but in between each is <p></p> but in the post there's nothing there